# How to apply a function against a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a df that stores medical records and I need to identify the first site that a person goes to after their discharge date. The df is grouped by ID.

There are 3 options: (1) within a group, if any of the rows have a begin_date that matches the first rows end_date, return that location as the first site (if there are two rows that meet this condition, either are correct). (2) if the first option does not exist, then select the first location after the initial location (3) else, if conditions 1 and 2 do not exist, then return 'Home'

```
ID    color  begin_date    end_date     location
1     red    2017-01-01    2017-01-07   initial
1     green  2017-01-05    2017-01-07   nursing
1     blue   2017-01-07    2017-01-15   rehab
1     red    2017-01-11    2017-01-22   Health
2     red    2017-02-22    2017-02-26   initial
2     green  2017-02-26    2017-02-28   nursing
2     blue   2017-02-26    2017-02-28   rehab
3     red    2017-03-11    2017-03-22   initial
4     red    2017-04-01    2017-04-07   initial
4     green  2017-04-05    2017-04-07   nursing
4     blue   2017-04-10    2017-04-15   Health
```

Expected Result:

```
ID   first_site
1    rehab
2    nursing
3    home
4    nursing
```

My attempt is below. I get an error of `"None of [Int64Index([8], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"` with not much online help about the error. 
If I remove the `elif` condition regarding val2, then I do not run into an error.

```
def First(x):
   #compare each group first and see if there are any locations that match 
   val = x.loc[x['begin_date'] == x['end_date'].iloc[0], 'location']
   #find the first location after the initial stay
   val2 = x.loc[x[x.location=='initial'].index+1, 'location']
   if not val.empty:
       return val.iloc[0]
   elif not val2.empty:
       return val2.iloc[0]
   else:
       return 'Home'

final = df.groupby('ID').apply(First).reset_index(name='first_site')
print (final)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line produces the error.  Please post the Traceback.

Comment: The `final = df...` line, which then points to `val2 = x...`.

Comment: I replaced the code for val2 with another approach that yields the same list...`val2 = x.groupby('ID').nth(1)['location']` and that worked! But I do not understand why the first approach was throwing that error.

Comment: How do you expect to get 'rehab' for index==1?

Comment: `'ID'` == 3 only has one row. remove that row and try your original.  You were trying to index a position that wasn't there.

Comment: @PaulaThomas because the end date of the initial location matches the begin date of the rehab claim.

Comment: @wwii the strange thing is if you run `df.loc[df[df.location=='initial'].index+1, 'location']` outside of the function then a df is returned. That is throwing me off since it works by itself but not in the function.

Comment: Try your `val2` expression with `x = df[df['ID'] == 3]`.  ID #3 didn't go anywhere after the initial location.

Comment: For `ID==4` you really want to return the next place listed, even though they weren't yet discharged? If you wanted the first place after the actual discharge, this can be done simply with `pandas.merge_asof`

Comment: @ALollz - I'd like to see an answer with `pandas.merge_asof`.  OP would probably accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'ID' == 3` only has one row - the `val2` expression is trying to index a position that isn't there.

Check to see if a group has only one row first.

```
def First(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return_value = 'Home'
    else:
        val = x.loc[x['begin_date'] == x['end_date'].iloc[0], 'location']
        val2 = x.loc[x[x.location=='initial'].index+1, 'location']
        if not val.empty:
            return_value =  val.iloc[0]
        elif not val2.empty:
            return_value =  val2.iloc[0]
    return return_value

gb = df.groupby('ID')

>>> gb.apply(First)
ID
1      rehab
2    nursing
3       Home
4    nursing
dtype: object
>>>
```